# ¿Por qué el coxis se llama también "hueso de la alegría", "hueso dulce" y "hueso palomo"?

Tags: etimología, sustantivos, cuerpo-humano

El [coxis](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxis) es la última pieza ósea de la columna vertebral.

En el DLE se encuentran otras denominaciones para este hueso:

[hueso de la alegría](https://dle.rae.es/hueso?m=form2#DQFntpZ), [hueso dulce](https://dle.rae.es/hueso?m=form2#9TqHbxn) y [hueso palomo](https://dle.rae.es/hueso?m=form2#9UJ1gk0)

¿De donde vienen esas denominaciones?

Answer (score 1):

**El Cóccix o Coxis**

El coxis, conocido popularmente también como rabadilla, es el término que señala una parte muy concreta dentro de los huesos referidos a las extremidades inferiores.

[image]

*Hueso propio de los vertebrados que carecen de cola, formado por la unión de las últimas vértebras y articulado por su base en el hueso sacro.*

---

**INTRODUCCIÓN**

Los diferentes nombres que han ido apareciendo a lo largo del tiempo, "*hueso sacro" (los griegos llaman al coxis «hueso sacro»), "hueso palomo", "hueso dulce", "hueso alegría" (por este motivo, también de la risa)*, lo han hecho a partir de diferentes realidades, que a su vez, han ido desfigurándose en denominaciones y deformaciones más populares y de más fácil reconocimiento por el común, apuntando a zonas del cuerpo generalmente más amplias situadas al final de la columna vertebral. Así para un simple dolor de espalda, localizado en la parte baja del dorso, es fácil aludir a él de forma popular, diciendo; me duele el hueso dulce, me duele el hueso del culo, me duele el hueso palomo... sin entrar a singularizar al área estricta del coxis.

**Distintas localizaciones que muestran lugares, vistos desde el exterior, cuando alguien siente que le duele el coxis**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Estudio Etimológico**

En cuanto a la deriva etimológica no he encontrado un estudio concreto que haga referencia a estos nombres y menos que abarquen su conjunto, salvo aquellos rumores populares circulantes que definen y relacionan un tipo de hueso, identificado popularmente de forma un poco abstracta al final de la columna vertebral, con el sobrenombre o apodo con el que se distinguen.

De esta manera encontramos que el "***hueso sacro***", es el hueso sagrado que se entregaba a los dioses en determinados sacrificios, que el "***hueso palomo***", seria tal, porque tiene la forma del pico de un palomo, el "***hueso alegría***" (*también de la risa*), porque irónicamente es una forma de describir como afectan los golpes en esa zona, como "*hueso odiado*", incluso relacionan las dolencias de ese, "*hueso de la alegría*", con la práctica de determinadas posturas de carácter sexual, así también según algunos llamado, de la "alegría", por esta razón y por último, el también "***hueso dulce***", con otra curiosa procedencia popular, pues seria el hueso preferido por algunos pueblos caníbales.

A partir de aquí, he intentado reunir e indagar en algunas de estas "*etimologías populares*" como base para analizar uno a uno estos apelativos, estudiándolos desde el inicio. Siendo por lo general complicados de hallar y más de resumir.

---

**PROCEDENCIA DE LAS PALABRAS. EL ETIMOLOGO.**

En Etimología, las procedencias de las voces pueden deberse a innumerables justificaciones, la existencia de costumbres, efectividad de causas, contigüidad, motivaciones espontáneas, o hasta claros ejemplos de derivación fonética, enlace y composición, pasando por los que dimanan de lugares próximos o tienen su origen en otras lenguas, incluso a veces son combinatorias de varias a la vez. En cualquier caso, hallarlas siempre es una mezcla de prudencia, antigua *τέχνη*, en el arcaico sentido griego, y principios heredados del positivismo lingüístico.

---

**HUESO PALOMO**

La procedencia de la voz, "**Hueso Palomo**", surgiría primeramente  en el ámbito rural, ya que designaba originalmente una parte del cuerpo del ganado en la zona de la grupa (*actualmente se entiende las ancas o caderas, los cuadriles, la parte superior de las nalgas y el muslo de la cola*).

[image]

*Hueso Palomo ubicado en la región Sacro-Coxal*

La "Palomilla" era el nombre que se daba para designar vulgarmente a la grupa, por haber llamado así, los antiguos veterinarios o albéitares, al hueso que le sirve de base en la zona sacro-coxal, **hueso palomo**, por estar éste situado en un lugar cercano a la evacuación de excrementos. Llamase palomina al estiércol de las palomas, palomino a las manchas de las deposiciones o palometa a la raya de excremento que queda en la ropa interior después de hacer caca y no haberse lavado bien el trasero, siendo pues, "palomo", una corrupción del indicativo que muestran estas mismas palabras, pues suele el ganado estar manchado de fiemo, siendo al fin en uno y en otro caso, "palomo" el estiércol de estos excrementos de animales y "**hueso palomo**" el lugar cercano al órgano defecador de los excrementos de los mismos.

*La Grupa es la parte del cuerpo que se extiende desde el extremo de los lomos hasta el origen de la cola, limitada lateralmente por las ancas. La parte que esencialmente le sirve de base es el hueso sacro, perteneciendo a la parte pélvica y teniendo por superficie ósea el sacro y los coxales, cubiertos estos por los músculos glúteos, psoas e isquiotibiales. La Grupa es la parte que más varia en su conformación según las especies y razas.*

*Cuando sobresale mucho la punta de la grupa se llama puntiaguda o alta de palomilla. Por medio de la grupa se trasmiten al tronco los esfuerzos de las extremidades superiores.*

---

**HUESO DULCE**

Entre otras cosas, en un principio pensé que podría estar relacionado con el "*Hueso Palomo*", en el sentido de que es esta parte de donde se obtienen los bistecs más **dulces**, suaves y jugosos del animal.

Igualmente recordé los "Huesos de Santo" un dulce de mazapán con forma de canutillo y relleno de yema dulce llamado así desde el S. XVII y su relación con el "Hueso Sacro", Santo/Sacro.

Sin embargo el "**Hueso Dulce**", ha sido un "hueso" en un principio chocante y en cierto modo ambivalente y duplicado, es decir, por alguna razón, que excede a este contenido, también se denomina "*Hueso Dulce*" y "*Hueso de la Risa*" a la neuritis del "codo", relacionando ambos nombres con los que se dan para el "coxis", quizás como simple copia que describe algún tipo de neuritis a ambos lados, pero enturbiando con su semejanza de homografía el acercamiento inicial al término.

[image]

*De la Zarzuela Cómica "Vía libre". Impresa Año 1893. De Ruperto Chapí, Carlos Arniches y Barrera, Celso Lucio y López.*

[image]

*El Joven y el mar de W.Rodman Philbrick*

[image]

*https://fisiovitalima.wixsite.com/fisiovitalima/single-post/2016/02/17/neuritis-del-mediano-o-hueso-dulce*

Indudablemente existe una relación codo/coxis con parecidas dolencias y trastornos músculo-esqueléticos ya que las mismas percepciones irradiadas se originan en diversas profesiones cuando por distintas razones se producen desgarros en los ligamentos, distensiones, dolores en las piernas, muñecas, manos, zonas normalmente en que, se pierde la sensibilidad, se tiene sensación de hormigueo, problemas de circulación sanguínea, adormecimiento en dedos u otras regiones que pueden reducir la movilidad o en las que se puede sufrir lesiones. Así existen profesiones en las se pasa mucho tiempo de pie, como panaderos, reposteros, pasteleros, confiteros, turroneros, churreros, galleteros... o en las que se esta mucho tiempo sentado como mecanógrafo, oficinista, diseñador... y que acarrean distintos tipos de traumatismos parecidos y relacionados que hacen que se apliquen nombres iguales o parecidos que intentan describir aparentes manifestaciones.

Una vez superada y comentada esta curiosa e inicial coincidencia, en el caso especial que nos ocupa, hay que decir que el "**hueso dulce**" ubicado en el coxis, debe su nombre a una ocurrencia parecida a la que nos hemos referido más arriba, al hablar del "*hueso palomo*", en la existencia de un término próximo con el que muestra cierta afinidad.

En este último sentido, es importante reconocer las distintas maneras que se tienen para denominar al "***culo***" pues entre estas aflora una bastante interesante que nos da una pista inestimable, ya que el "*culo*" fue también popular por ser conocido como "***pan dulce***", aludiendo a la figura particularmente abombada como la que se aprecia en un "**pan**", con la peculiaridad de que el "**pan dulce**" posee una forma aún más abultada y redondeada que la de un pan normal, silueta ésta especialmente acentuada en el caso del "*pompi*" de muchas mujeres, por tanto, llamar a esa región "**hueso dulce**", sería la manera menos grotesca o vulgar de decir, "*hueso del culo*", ya que el "**hueso dulce**" es el hueso que esta por encima del "*pan dulce*", es decir, del "*culo*".

[image]

*El "Pan Dulce", posee una forma más abombada y redondeada que la de un "pan" normal y que por su forma nos recuerda al culo.*

- Pan dulce: Forma de llamarle a la cola de una mujer. La cola es el trasero, nalgas, culo... (*curiosamente y por otro motivo se dice, cóccix o "hueso de la cola"*).
- Sinónimos de "Pan dulce": nalgas, asentaderas, culo, trasero, posaderas, poto, cola, culo, huesito dulce, popa, pompi.

---

**HUESO DE LA ALEGRIA**

Quizás sea éste el término que aparente ser el más fácil de hallar, siendo en verdad el más complejo de los tres vocablos estudiados. El llamado "**hueso de la alegría**" esta relacionado con la zona pélvica de la mujer, el útero, los embarazos y los abortos y en nada tiene que ver con aquella idea primera que se nos viene cuando leemos la palabra "*Alegría*" como un sentimiento grato que aúna actos que expresan gozo, júbilo y alegría.

*El dolor de coxis puede desencadenarse por presión, pequeños traumatismos repetidos o tras un parto complicado. La cintura pélvica está formada por dos coxales y el sacro. El hueso coxal es un hueso plano que conecta el sacro con el fémur y une de esta manera el tronco con la extremidad inferior.*

[image]
*Pelvis ósea femenina*.

[image]
*Huesos que componen la pelvis: 1) Sacro; 2) Iliaco; 3) Ísquion; 4) Púbico; 5) Sínfisis púbica*

[image]
*Piso de la pelvis. Se ven las relaciones entre útero y sacro.*

*Los ligamentos utero-sacros son una estructura de apoyo firme que unen el cuello del útero al sacro*.

El coxis tiene forma triangular y se articula con el hueso sacro, que compone la parte trasera de la pelvis, y al que se une mediante los ligamentos sacro-coxígeos. Estos ligamentos están muy inervados, es decir, muestran la transmisión de corriente o impulsos eléctricos que consiguen la activación de movimientos y funciones de órganos y estructuras, por lo que su rotura, desgarro o distensión, frecuentemente causado por un traumatismo directo, es muy doloroso.

De esta manera es fácil hallar en esta región sacrococcigea, traumatismos, quistes sacros desarrollados cerca del coxis y que producen fístulas, tumores de distinta consideración, infecciones, partos difíciles o abortos que por diversas circunstancias precisen de un raspado o legrado de las paredes del útero.

El legrado se considera que es una operación quirúrgica menor en la que se utiliza una legra o cureta y anestesia local para raer la superficie de los huesos o insertándose como instrumento en el útero para eliminar tejido o extraer contenido del mismo mediante raspado o cucharillado.

En este sentido, al "**legrado**", en términos médicos, hoy término ya en desuso, se le conocía como "**Alegrar**", así *los cirujanos atienden con sus instrumentos a raer, alegrar, raspar*.

En un tiempo precario un gran número de estas prácticas tenían como fin, por numerosas razones, la interrupción del embarazo, ya fuere por un parto dificultoso asociado a un peligro para la vida de la madre, las mujeres adúlteras que deseaban ocultar su turbación, las que simplemente pretendían conservar su belleza, las que tenían un útero demasiado pequeño para soportar una gestación, etc.

[image]

*Alegrar, Cirugía legrar.*

En cualquier caso en esta época antigua, la mayoría de los legrados, apuntaban a esta región sacrococcigea, practicándose una cirugía en la que se "***alegraba***" (*también con el sentido de aligerar o aliviar* ) la herida, sometiéndola a este tipo de operaciones, eliminando, raspando o extrayendo un contenido que por sí hubiera supuesto un peligro si se hubiera mantenido alojado ahí, por lo que el "**hueso de la alegría**" es la evolución popular del término "***alegrar***" referido al legrado que de manera más común y sencilla designaba a un hueso indeterminado, cercano a la región sacroilíaca, donde se realizaban este tipo de intervenciones.

El término hoy en día

**Alegrar2**

De a-1 y legra.

1. tr. Mar. Agrandar un taladro o agujero cualquiera.

**2. tr. Med. desus. legrar.**

https://dle.rae.es/alegrar?m=form

Comment: La "Palomilla" era el nombre que se daba para designar vulgarmente a la grupa, por haber llamado así, los antiguos veterinarios o albéitares, al hueso que le sirve de base en la zona sacro-coxal, "Hueso Palomo". La Grupa es la parte del cuerpo que se extiende desde el extremo de los lomos hasta el origen de la cola, la parte que esencialmente le sirve de base es el hueso sacro, perteneciendo a la parte pélvica. A mi me llamó la atención la ocurrencia de que alguien llamara al "culo", "pan dulce".

Comment: La gente antiguamente y también mucha hoy en día, no sabe donde esta situado el coxis o lo que es. Se habla de coxis, pero popularmente se hace referencia a una región más amplia del cuerpo.

Comment: La única relación codo/coxis en un sentido lato, se refiere únicamente y solo a las formas en las que pueden ser descritas las sensaciones y trastornos músculo-esqueléticos sobre percepciones irradiadas como perdida de sensibilidad, sensación de hormigueo, problemas de circulación sanguínea, adormecimiento de ciertas áreas... Igualmente la utilización del nombre "Hueso Dulce" para el codo, contrasta con la utilización del nombre "Hueso Dulce" para el coxis. Lo más seguro es que en ese encuentro lo único que se halle es un intento por describir parecidas sensaciones de dolor, pero no de fondo.